# PCB tracks missing

Tags: altium

I am working on audio preamp project in [Altium](https://www.altium.com/). I have 8 analog inputs, connected to belonging relay using [Altium's Multi Channel Design](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/((Multi-Sheet+and+Multi-Channel+Design))_AD):
[image: Audio Inputs]
Now, when I compile this project and update PCB, I get tracks, which connect audio input and it's relay for only first input:
[image: Tracks problem]
Tracks should be there for **every** audio input, what did I wrong?

Comment: you didn't name the traces EXACTLY the same did you? you did do "Audio_input_left1, Audio...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make you schematic work as drawn you only need a small modification.
Try this:
[image]

Comment: This was hard one for me to crack, I am still newbie, it works now!!!!!

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have to define the connection between the two repeat sheet symbols as a bus instead of wire. Looking at the example in the Altium help file shows all repeat channels first have a bustap, with the name of the bus, than a bus with the same name and the '[1..8]' brackets.

[image: example from altium]